# Generating Possible Network Graphs Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph, network-programming, networkx

I want to generate all the possible network graphs from a list of arrays. For example:

```html
OPSIYON  1 [[4], [10]]
OPSIYON  2 [[9, 1], [13]]
OPSIYON  3 [[1], []]
OPSIYON  4 [[9, 9], [11]]
OPSIYON  5 [[4, 4], [7]]
```

In this case I have 5 different array here and every array have inside arrays. Please think like I have 5 different groups. I want to see all the possible edges between groups and draw it.

For example:

I can add OPSIYON 2 Group to OPSIYON 1. In OPSIYON 2, we have default edges like 9 to 1 and to 13

(9->1)-> 13

I can add it to 1 like

4 -> 10 -> OPSIYON 2

Finally I want to generate many possible network graphs and visualize them.,

How can I do it?

### EDIT FOR REQUEST

[example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mp5F2.png)
https://404store.com/2018/01/07/EkranResmi2018-01-0720.35.50.png

OK, In the above image, left handside, I put 4 groups with their nodes. Actually [2, [1,3]] means I am talking about first group. Problem is, I want to connect groups with their nodes (like in the right handside) randomly. If I can, I want to generate all the possible edges and generate many many graphs.

There are some rules :

1. 1 NODE 1 EDGE:
   For example, like in the image, if I will connect group 1 to group to via node 5, I can create any new edge from node 5

Oh yeah this is the only rule :)

Above codesnipt, I create 5 array and as you can see OPSION 1 is Group 4 OPSIYON 2 is group 2 and so on.

I m looking for your help ! Thank You!

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking for.  Can you give an example input and say exactly what the output would be?

Comment: @Joel hello, thanks for your respond. I edited the question with some example. Thank you for your help!